# rails: how to save a big array in session? (ActionDispatch::Cookies::CookieOverflow)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, session, cookies

Im trying to save a array in a session which is much bigger than 4 KB.

In this case the: ActionDispatch::Cookies::CookieOverflow Error occures.

Does anybody have a hint how to save a bigger array in a session? Saving it to the db is not what I want.

Thanks,
Markus

Comment: you have to change your session store , why you cant use ActiveRecord store? .

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cookie overflow in rails application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9473808/cookie-overflow-in-rails-application)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need change your session_store and don't use the cookie_store. You can use the active_record_store by example.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Im not sure how to change that store... my second question is if active_record_store is better for a big amount of data and a lot of different users?

Comment: I tried to use: config.session_store(:active_record_store) in the application.rb file, but it didn't help so far...

Comment: Have you add and launch the migration too ?

Comment: @Markus

See my answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9473808/cookie-overflow-in-rails-application) May be this one is helping you

Comment: what if I don't want to store anything in the DB how I can rescue the error? I tried rescue_from ActionDispatch::Cookies::CookieOverflow, :with => :render_404 in the ApplicationController but it didn't work