# Cookie overflow in rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

> ActionDispatch::Cookies::CookieOverflow in UsersController#create

I have this error when I try to open the page. I do not know how to debug this error. Do you have any suggestion for this problem?

```
def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])
  sign_in @user

  if @user.save
    @user.folders.create(:folder_name=>"Default Folder", :user_id=>@user.id)
    flash[:success] = "Welcome to Bunch<it>! "
    redirect_to @user
  else
    @title = "Sign up"
    render 'new'
  end
end


def sign_in(user)
  cookies.permanent.signed[:remember_token] = [user.id, user.salt]
  session[:current_user] = user
  current_user = user
end
```

Comment: this error comes when you have a large data/object in session. Can you share the code for create action in controller?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782611/rails-how-to-save-a-big-array-in-session-actiondispatchcookiescookieoverf ?

Comment: While the answers about changing your session store are correct, i'd question why you want to store the entire user in the session. If you have to store something, store the user_id (although that's already in your cookie)

Comment: Simply go to the browser cache store, and clear cookies belonging to that specific website url. for me it happens mostly in localhost.

Comment: I had created a user model with `Devise` and I hadn't restarted my development server after running the migrations. Once I did, the error stopped.

Answer (score 168, accepted):

You've got a 4kb limit on what you can store in a cookie, and when Rails converts your object into text for writing to the cookie its probably bigger than that limit.

Ruby on Rails `ActionDispatch::Cookies::CookieOverflow` error

That way this `CookieOverflow` Error occurs.

The easiest way to solve this one is, you need change your session_store and don't use the `cookie_store`. You can use the `active_record_store` by example.

Here is the steps

1. Generate a migration that creates the session table

   ```
   rake db:sessions:create
   ```
2. Run the migration

   ```
   rake db:migrate
   ```
3. Modify `config/initializers/session_store.rb` from

   ```
   (App)::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, :key => 'xxx'
   ```

   to

   ```
   (App)::Application.config.session_store :active_record_store
   ```

Once you’ve done the three steps, restart your application. Rails will now use the sessions table to store session data, 
and you won’t have the 4kb limit.

Comment: is it possible to see that cookie to check this out

Comment: just curious - is this a 4kb limit per session, or per app?

Comment: @colllin, it's per session.

Comment: do i need the `active_record_store` gem?

Comment: or is it part of rails4

Comment: what if I don't want to store anything in the DB how I can rescue the error? I tried rescue_from ActionDispatch::Cookies::CookieOverflow, :with => :render_404 in the ApplicationController but it didn't work

Comment: leave everything above and just follow https://github.com/rails/activerecord-session_store

Comment: Instead of changing the storage mechanism for your sessions, I recommend storing less info in your session. See suggestion from @cianmce

Answer (score 84):

To make the `:active_record_store` functionality works in Rails 4/5, you must add the [activerecord-session_store](https://github.com/rails/activerecord-session_store) gem to your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'activerecord-session_store'
```

then run the migration generator:

```
rails generate active_record:session_migration
rake db:migrate
```

And finally set your session store in `config/initializers/session_store.rb`:

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :active_record_store, :key => '_my_app_session'
```

*UPDATE:*

If anyone is receiving a `null value in column "session_id" violates not-null constraint` message in rails 4, there's a [workaround in github](https://github.com/rails/activerecord-session_store/issues/6#issuecomment-26214581)(not tested). You must to create an initializer with `ActiveRecord::SessionStore::Session.attr_accessible :data, :session_id`

Comment: Did you not get an error when using this gem? I get the following : `ERROR:  null value in column "session_id" violates not-null constraint`

Comment: @Peter It didn't happened me, but [here](https://github.com/rails/activerecord-session_store/issues/6) still appears as an open issue. My only advise is write a comment in that issue to watch it until someone put a fix. Sorry :/

Comment: @Peter I'm not sure if is too late, but anyway check my updated answer

Comment: After running "rails generate active_record:session_migration" don't forget to run: "rake db:migrate"!

Comment: what if I don't want to store anything in the DB how I can rescue the error? I tried rescue_from ActionDispatch::Cookies::CookieOverflow, :with => :render_404 in the ApplicationController but it didn't work

Answer (score 31):

If you're seeing this, check that you're not blowing up some session data. In my case, it was thousands of the same message pumped into the flash message. Just saying.

I'll add that if you think the solution is to make your cookie store bigger (as most of the other answers suggest), you're probably better off rethinking what you're actually putting in cookies. If you need more than a couple of auth tokens, session ID's, and maybe a few layout/tracking cookies, you're living in the 90's.

Comment: I was deep merging some params to save state!

Comment: This was the cause of the error for me as well. Putting too much data into the flash message.

Comment: Yes, I had this issue when implementing OmniAuth-Keycloak strategy. Keycloak provides lots of information, including user's accesses list. Only a few is relevant for storing as a cookie ...

Comment: Gold! It was a flash message issue.

Comment: @user1185081, I am also implementing OmniAuth-Keycloak and I need to store access_token, refresh_token, id_token into session as those will be required to get the new access token and also to logout the user. How did you mange this?

Answer (score 10):

It's not a good idea to store a model object in the session.

Check out this railscast on this topic:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/13-dangers-of-model-in-session?autoplay=true

It's a better practice to store the id (user's id in this case) inside the session.
Then you won't have this problem.

(See Frederick Cheung comment above also).

Answer (score 10):

That error is because you are trying to serialize the user model
When storing an object in a cookie, rails will use [Marshal.dump](https://github.com/rails/activerecord-session_store/blob/bd7174ccc16f6b020e29bfb269fc43d8e4e48463/lib/active_record/session_store.rb#L65) which can produce a large amount of content since it's everything on the user record

Instead of storing the actual user record with `session[:current_user] = user` try just storing the users' ID then have a method a method to look up the user from that
e.g.

```
def sign_in(user)
  ...
  session[:current_user_id] = user.id
end

def current_user
  @current_user ||= User.find(session[:current_user_id])
end
```

Answer (score 9):

the error message clearly indicates the problem with cookie store size that's overflow.

Your sessions (by default in cookie) needs to be moved to Active record
store or memcache store to fix this issue.

For Databased sessions:

```
config.action_controller.session_store = :active_record_store
```

You need to create the session table as below

```
rake db:sessions:create
rake db:migrate
```

OR

For Memcache sessions:

```
config.action_controller.session_store = :mem_cache_store
```

Also you need to setup a mem cache server and configure it as below:

```
config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store, 'localhost', '127.0.0.1:11211',
{:namespace => 'myapp123'}
```

Answer (score 4):

my problem was because of code

```
rescue StandardError => e
  flash[:error] = "Error was #{error.message}"
end
```

the `error.message` was too big

Comment: That is correct, maximum size of the cookie is 4kb; then the flash is stored in the session it seems, then it overflows with that :error assigning

Answer (score 1):

This error appeared for me when I was running a specs. After updating Capybara from 1.x to 2.x.
Just rake tmp:clear solved it.