# Rails - Too much data in flash notice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, flash

I have a flash notice that causes cookie overflow error:

```
candidates = Hiring::Candidate.find(params[:candidate_ids])
notice     = render_to_string(partial: '/hiring/candidates/new_candidates_assigned',    locals: {candidate: candidates})

redirect_to path, notice: notice
```

I suppose it's because of a lot of object passed to flash. How this can be avoiding?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9473808/cookie-overflow-in-rails-application could help as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the message you want to display in your controller

```
redirect_to path, :notice => "Successfully assigned new candidate"
```

Render the partial in your view and pass the flash notice as a local.

```
<%= render partial => '/hiring/candidates/new_candidates_assigned', :locals => {:flash_notice => flash[:notice]}%>
```