# ActionDispatch::Cookies::CookieOverflow

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have found this question:
[Cookie overflow in rails application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9473808/cookie-overflow-in-rails-application)
And in accepted answer in punkt 3 there is this:
`(App)::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, :key => 'xxx'`
How do I get this 'xxx' key?

Answer (score 0):

```
Rails.application.config.session_options[:key]
```

Comment: do I need to generate in manually? Why is it 'xxx' in the example and not `Rails.application.config.session_options[:key]
` ?