# Rails 4: Cookie overflow when importing CSV

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, ruby-on-rails-4, cookies

I am attempting to analyze CSV before importing into my database but am encountering a `ActionDispatch::Cookies::CookieOverflow` error.

**controller**

```
def bulk_upload_weigh_ins
    @response = WeighIn.check_file(params[:file])
    redirect_to import_weigh_ins_path, notice: @response
end
```

**model**

```
def self.check_file(file)
    status = {
        name_error: [],
        weigh_in_error: []
    }
    count = 0
    CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: @weigh_in_cols) do |row|
        hashed_row = row.to_hash
        user = User.find_by(scale_id: hashed_row["scale_id"])
        if user == nil
            status[:name_error] << [hashed_row["name"], hashed_row["scale_id"]]
        elsif user.check_ins.with_no_weigh_ins.length != 1
            status[:weigh_in_error] << [hashed_row["name"], hashed_row["scale_id"]]
        else
            count += 1
        end
        status[:number_of_success] = count
    end
    return status
end
```

**I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9473808/cookie-overflow-in-rails-application) post but I'm not sure I should be using doing the same fix.  Is there a better way to set this up?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the following to fix this:

1. `rails generate active_record:session_migration`
2. `rake db:migrate`
3. Changed the line in config/initializers/session_store.rb to: `Rails.application.config.session_store :active_record_store`
4. Restarted by server
5. **Restarted my browser (wasn't obvious to me)**

Hope this helps someone