# Getting Cookie Overflow in rails application(REDMINE)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, session, redmine

```
ActionDispatch::Cookies::CookieOverflow (ActionDispatch::Cookies::CookieOverflow):
actionpack (4.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:529:in `[]='
```

I am getting this error when hitting redmine rest api. The simple get api like url1 works fine but when it come to complex url as url2 the application throws cookie overflow.

```
url1: localhost:3000/issues.json?page=1&limit=100
url2: http://localhost:3000/issues.json?key=292fe116d13d5f5db8a0e3f2b031f1e57ad1c882&f[]=project_id&op[project_id]=!&v[project_id][]=505&f[]=project_id&op[project_id]=!&v[project_id][]=478&f[]=project_id&op[project_id]=!&v[project_id][]=366&f[]=project_id&op[project_id]=!&v[project_id][]=419&f[]=project_id&op[project_id]=!&v[project_id][]=343&f[]=project_id&op[project_id]=!&v[project_id][]=345&f[]=project_id&op[project_id]=!&v[project_id][]=512&f[]=project_id&op[project_id]=!&v[project_id][]=487&f[]=project_id&op[project_id]=!&v[project_id][]=473&f[]=project_id&op[project_id]=!&v[project_id][]=509&f[]=project_id&op[project_id]=!&v[project_id][]=520&f[]=project_id&op[project_id]=!&v[project_id][]=404&f[]=project_id&op[project_id]=!&v[project_id][]=440&f[]=project_id&op[project_id]=!&v[project_id][]=389&f[]=project_id&op[project_id]=!&v[project_id][]=467&f[]=project_id&op[project_id]=!&v[project_id][]=501&f[]=project_id&op[project_id]=!&v[project_id][]=474&f[]=project_id&op[project_id]=!&v[project_id][]=471&f[]=project_id&op[project_id]=!&v[project_id][]=480&f[]=project_id&op[project_id]=!&v[project_id][]=507&f[]=project_id&op[project_id]=!&v[project_id][]=383&f[]=project_id&page=1&limit=100
```

I have not stored anything but username, cas ticket in session as:

```
 request.session['cas'] = { 'user' => user, 'ticket' => ticket, 'extra_attributes' => [] }
```

I have searched for the solution in many forums. All said donot save unnecessary data but all i am saving are username and cas ticket. When i print session this is the result:

```
puts(session.to_hash)

{"session_id"=>"fbe61cf9fd1c2ef0111d5d84a1a374c2", "cas"=>{"user"=>"user@gmail.com", "ticket"=>"ST-27189-R20MW7GBWaLWNJvl1aMi-localhost", "extra_attributes"=>[]}}
```

But when inspect session as below i get loads of gibberish data like below.I saw that the ActiveRecord stuff and query params from the GET is indeed part of the session.

```
puts(session.inspect)

[result]: https://textsaver.flap.tv/lists/3caw "Click here for session.inspect output"
```

Since i am a newbie and just starting ruby on rails any suggestions will be highly appreciated. 
Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

That second url with many parameters is quite long and it bloats session since it is present in `original_fullpath`, `query_string` and other variables in session. And cookie store has limits - there is only 4kb.

I suggest to change session store from cookie to [database](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9474262/946500) or [memcache](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14336149/946500) as explained in linked answers.

Edit:
Up-to-date info can be found in [docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#session).

Comment: those links are from 5 -8 years ago, are they still useful?

Comment: @MayraNavarro original question was about ruby-on-rails-3, so I thought it will be OK to provide info relevant to that time.
Now there are some differences: memcache is somewhat deprecated (use CacheStore instead) and storing sessions in database requires gem.
I added new link to the answer, thank you.